# a,Remove the duplicate based on elements in character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame like this, it contain 3 or more characters separated by comma (,) I want to remove the row if it contain same characters.

```
x <-c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <-c("a,a,a","a,a,b,c","b,c,a","b,b,b,b","a,b,b,c")
df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

desired output is

```
x <-c(2,3,5)
y <-c("a,a,b,c","b,c,a","a,b,b,c")
df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

Comment: Someone can help you reach the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows` to split the comma-separated values into different rows, remove those groups where there are only 1 distinct values and summarise the data again.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(y) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(y) > 1) %>%
  summarise(y = toString(y))

#      x y      
#  <dbl> <chr>  
#1     2 a, b, c
#2     3 b, c, a
#3     5 a, b, c
```

---

In base R :

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$y, ','), function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1, ]
```

Comment: I have no idea about "In base R" part

Comment: I have updated the question because it can be contain same element but not all. so do you have any idea?. actually its my fault.

Comment: My answer keeps only those rows where you have more than 1 unique character. So my answer still works for your updated dataset and gives the expected output.

Comment: @Isuru 1) My code gives the desired output as shown in your post. If you don't want this please give us a better example which represents your actual problem. 2) It is your responsibility to make sure that the example you share accurately represents the data you have so as to avoid situations where the answer works on sample data that you share but not on your actual data. 3) You should not change your question after an answer is posted nor extend it in the comments. If you have additional questions ask it as a new question.

Comment: Yes, but if there same x values (2,2) it concatenate  all rows

Comment: You should include an example showing that. In that case you can create a column with row number. `df %>% group_by(row = row_number()) %>% tidyr::separate_rows(y) %>% group_by(row) %>% filter(n_distinct(y) > 1) %>% summarise(y = toString(y))`